# Populate column value with corresponding data from another dataframe (merge??)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. First:

```
    country city
0   Norway    a
1   Norway    a
2   Norway    a
3   Norway    b
4   Norway    b
5   Norway    b
6   Sweden    c
7   Sweden    c
8   Sweden    c
9   Sweden    c
10  Sweden    d
11  Sweden    d
12  Sweden    d
```

and second:

```
  city  region
0    a       1
1    a       2
2    b       3
3    b       4
4    c       5
5    c       6
6    c       7
7    d       8
```

How can I get the following dataframe? We just need to assign a correct country to the corresponding city as a new column in the second dataframe.

```
  country city  region
0  Norway    a       1
1  Norway    a       2
2  Norway    b       3
3  Norway    b       4
4  Sweden    c       5
5  Sweden    c       6
6  Sweden    c       7
7  Sweden    d       8
```

I have tried to use merge and mapping, but could not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `dict` that maps `city` names to `country` names, and then use that as a map for the `pd.Series.map` method:

```
df2['country'] = df2['city'].map(dict(zip(df1.city, df1.country)))

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  city  region country
0    a       1  Norway
1    a       2  Norway
2    b       3  Norway
3    b       4  Norway
4    c       5  Sweden
5    c       6  Sweden
6    c       7  Sweden
7    d       8  Sweden
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both dataframes, but first you need to drop duplicates in the first dataframe:

`pd.merge(df1.drop_duplicates(), df2)`

Output:

```
  country city  region
0  Norway    a       1
1  Norway    a       2
2  Norway    b       3
3  Norway    b       4
4  Sweden    c       5
5  Sweden    c       6
6  Sweden    c       7
7  Sweden    d       8
```

Comment: That is exactly how I ended up solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', left_on='city',right_on='city')
```